# How to test if a window is open from a batch file even if there are multiple windows from the same program?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tasklist

I am using a batch file to make sure that an emulator that I am using exits completely when I close the game window. The problem is that the program (PCSX2 if that matters) has multiple windows, the game window, another window used for configuring the program and potentially a console window. I am using this to find the window and do some if statements later.

```
for /F "tokens=2" %%b in ('tasklist /V /NH /FI "imagename eq %emulatorImage%" ^| find "Slot:"') do (set tmp=%%b)
{some if statments}
```

If the game window is minimized and the other windows are not then this does not result in anything because tasklist only shows one window at a time. So in its current state, if I have the other windows on the desktop and then minimize the game window, the batch file thinks that the window is closed. I am open to external programs but would prefer it be built-in. How can I find the window even with the other ones open?

EDIT:

I ran this

```
TaskList /V /Fo CSV 1>"_$.csv"
```

And depending on what window I have in focus the output changes.
When Game window is minimized and the other windows are not this is the output:

```
"pcsx2.exe","18732","Console","2","235,424 K","Running","LAPTOP-0VMQFKAJ\ooliv","0:00:56","PCSX2  1.4.0"
```

When I have the Game window in focus:

```
"pcsx2.exe","18732","Console","2","235,520 K","Running","LAPTOP-0VMQFKAJ\ooliv","0:01:23","Slot: 0 | Speed: 100% (59.96) | Limiter: Normal | GSdx D3D11 HW | 640x448 | Auto | Interlaced | EE:   7% | GS:   0%"
```

As you can see depending on where the windows are and which is in focus the output changes, so I can not test if the window exists reliably.

Comment: Can you please run `TaskList /V /Fo CSV 1>"_$.csv"`, then edit `_$.csv` to limit it only to the three lines relevant to your three windows. Once you've done that, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58978918/edit) to include that output.

Comment: Based upon what you've added as an edit, can you please try better to explain what you're trying to achieve. You initially told us, that there were multple PCSX2 windows open, the game window, another window used for configuring the program and potentially a console window. You've only provided the information for a console window, _(which is also, confusingly the game window)_, so how are we supposed to help you to select one from the others?

Comment: @Compo That is exactly my problem. For whatever reason, that is what the tasklist gives me. It only sees one window at a time, depending on which was in focus/minimized. My guess is that because the windows are considered one process tasklist does not know witch window title to use. Whereas something like chrome has a different PID for each window/tab.